# Click "yes" double when closing form C#?

Tags: c#

I write a code for event close form C#. It works, but when I click "yes" to close form I must click twice.
What wrong with it? And how can I fix this problem?
Here is my code

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            Application.Exit();   
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks nice. Check that the method is doesnt called 2 times

Comment: Don't use `Application.Exit()`. It is unnecessary in this case. And shouldn't you `e.Cancel = true` in the `No` case?

Comment: should it be result == DialogResult.Yes ?

Comment: In your `if` block you say if user selected `No` then `Exit` program. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler version would be something like this:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Cancel = (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", 
                                 "Exit", 
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes);
 }
```

If the use clicks the `Yes` button, then `e.Cancel` will be set to true.
If `e.Cancel` is set to true, the form will not close.
otherwise let the form closing sequence run it's course.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic right now will run `e.Cancel = true` if you click yes, as in it cancels the closing.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, Application.Exit() is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: The event handler is probably not implemented in the form that is about to close, so you probably don't want (and don't need) to call `this.Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the Application.Exit will trigger the FormClosing event again. The solution is easier than you think:

```
if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = false; //It works as you expected 
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: while correct, the if..else is redundant, a shorter version would be `e.Cancel = (result != DialogResult.No);` or `e.Cancel = (result == DialogResult.Yes);`